# How to pass multiple state through link in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to pass more than one state for my next page which I'm redirecting from my another page.

I'm already passing one and that is working fine.

```
<Link to ={{pathname: "/CreateEventUser", state: { bucket_id: !this.state.selected_bucket.id ? this.state.recent_bucket : this.state.selected_bucket } }} >
 <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Create an Event</button>
</Link>
```

Now I have to pass two states. What is the syntax for that?

```
<Link to ={{pathname: "/EventDetailsUser", state: { bucket_id: !this.state.selected_bucket.id ? this.state.recent_bucket : this.state.selected_bucket, eventId: event.id}}} >
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `state` parameter in the location pathname accepts an object and hence you can pass as many values as you need by passing them as an object like below:

```
<Link to ={{
    pathname: "/CreateEventUser", 
    state: { 
        bucket_id: !this.state.selected_bucket.id ? this.state.recent_bucket : this.state.selected_bucket, 
        new_id: this.state.newID, 
        anotherValue: this.state.anotherValue 
    }
   }} >
 <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Create an Event</button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Hi, I know it is a old questions, but I have a doubt, I'm starting with React. In this answear I saw how to pass state vars, but how can I get these vars on the other view? I'm trying something like `this.props.location.state`, but it is not working. Can you help me?

Comment: @RicardoAlves if you refresh the view, the location state will be lost

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thank you, I'm going to find a way to keep some information if the user press F5

Comment: @RicardoAlves you can save it in localStorage

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri By the way is this a recommended approach to send state via Link tag? I mean what if we have like a lot of properties in state, would this still be a viable solution?

Answer (score 1):

way 1: This is how you will send multiple state through a link state:
send:

```
<Link
   to={{
      pathname: "/app/style/form",
      state: {
             item: item,
             styleList: styleList
      },
   }}
>
Go Button
</Link>
```

Here how you will receive data
receive:

```
let stateData = props.location.state
var styleUpdate = stateData["item"]
var styleList = stateData['styleList']
```

way 2:
you can also change the name of the variable you want to hold the state.(custom state name)
send:

```
<Link 
    to={{
        pathname: "/app/style/form", 
        styleList: styleList
    }}>
    Go Next
</Link>
```

receive:

```
let styleList = props.location.styleList
```

Answer (score 0):

As per updated react-router-dom

```
<Link
  to={{
       pathname: DESIRED_PATH,
     }}
  state={{ yourData: yourData}}
  style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
 >
   <Button
   >
       Navigate
   </Button>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `reeact-router-dom` - `^6.18.0`

```html
<Link className="mt-3" to="/auth/forgot-password" state={{type: "PASSWORD", domain: "your data in form of string/object/array/num/bool/etc"}}>Forgot Password?</Link>
```